# Extract input of a function in R

Tags: r, function, match

I wonder if there might be a way to extract the input value (`1:3`) used in `a` after running object `a`?

```
library(clubSandwich)

a <- constrain_equal(1:3)

Desired output: vector 1:3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like

```r
environment(a)$constraints
```

works for your example (`ls(environment(a))` shows you which objects are available).

Comment: Waiting to accept, thanks! Would it be *safer* to do: `foo <- function(cons = constrain_equal(1:3)){ environment(cons)$constraints }` and then run `foo()`?

Comment: I don't know why. Reading objects out of an environment should be harmless; it's only when you start to modify objects within environments (which don't follow R's usual copy-on-modify convention) that things can get confusing.